# subflow is not getting the value from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

When Flow 1 invokes apex action(AddString.mainMethod), The concatenated string 'finalString' is showing the results in Flow 1 from both the methods stringSet1 & stringSet2. Assigned the same value(finalString) to a String variable in Flow 2, In Flow 2 it is noted that only the first concatenation method results i.e. stringSet1() are visible and not the data from the method stringSet2.

```
public class wrapper{

     @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
     public string str1;

     @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
     public string str2;

     @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
     public string str3;

     @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
     public List<String> stringArray;
    }
    
    public class AddString{
     
     @InvocableMethod
     public static List<String> mainMethod(List<Wrapper> wrap){
       String finalString = stringSet1(wrap.get(0))+stringSet2(wrap.get(0).inputSet));
       return new List<String>{finalString};
     }
     private static string stringSet1(wrapper wr){
        return wr.str1+'\n'+wr.str2+'\n'+wr.str3+'\n';
     }
     
     private static string stringSet2(List<String> strSet){
         String tempStr;
         for(String str: strSet){
            tempStr+= strSet+'\n';
         }
         return tempStr;
     }
    }
```

Comment: `stringSet2` doesn't compile...

Comment: @sfdcfox - trying to understand here...I am retuning the value from mainMethod and assigning the same value to a variable in Flow2.  Not invoking the method from Flow 2.

Comment: In your example code here, `stringSet2` returns `strSet` which is a `List<String>`, but the return type is `String`.

Comment: @sfdcfox - was typo. updated the example code.  Each tempStr in for loop is a combination of label+value. strangely in Flow 2, only the labels from method stringSet2 are coming but not the value(data from method 1(stringSet1) of course).